# Issues with compiling using mex in matlab

Tags: matlab, gcc, mex

I am trying to compile with mex in matlab. However, I get the following error

You are using gcc version "4.8.1". The version currently supported with MEX is "4.7.x"

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: At the risk of stating the b******g obvious -- install and use gcc v4.7.x

Answer (score 1):

This is a warning, not an error.  You should get functional MEX files if your code is correct.